# spliting a column in a pd.dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a tsv file that I am trying to treat to have a proper format.

```
sample       path
A-1-Name   pathname
A-5-Name   pathname ....
```

This is the original dataframe, with two columns sample and path.
I wish to treat this dataframe to be like

```
sample    Name    path
A-1-      Name     pathname
A-5-      Name     pathname ...
```

like this, three columns that has the new 'Name' column, separated from the original 'sample' column.
The Names are arbitrary english words, and there are two '-' which throw me off a little.

Please provide some insight!
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract` to split your column:

```
df = df.pop('sample').str.extract('(?P<sample>\w+-\w+-)(?P<Name>.*)').join(df)
print(df)

# Output
  sample  Name      path
0   A-1-  Name  pathname
1   A-5-  Name  pathname
```

Comment: worked! thank you so much:)